# How to add a password protected repository to Sonatype Nexus?

Tags: authentication, sonatype

We're using Sonatype Nexus to manage different repositoryies. There's a request to add a password-protected repository to our "Public Repositories" group. The problem is, I don't really know how to accomplish this.

I can create a new repo and add it to the existing group, and there's the option for authentication, but how can I be sure to be doing this right? Searching the net only yields results for CREATING a protected repository, but nothing about adding an existing, password-protected remote repository.

If there are links to resources that explain how to tackle this particular problem, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the proxy repository's configuration tab click on "authentication (optional)", then enter the credentials for the remote site.

After you do this the status of the proxy repository in the repository list should show as "in service".  If it does then you're done.

If it shows "remote automatically blocked" then it didn't work, check the log for details about the problem.

Comment: In the process of setting up the mirror and trying some configurations, I had to click the "invalidate cache" button in nexus and clear out some cached instances in my local maven repo before I eventually succeeded.

Comment: Be careful that Nexus does not like ampersand in the password field. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41962215/how-to-type-in-sonatype-nexus-a-password-with-special-characters-in-proxy-repo