# How to type in Sonatype Nexus a password with special characters in proxy repo?

Tags: encoding, passwords, special-characters, nexus, sonatype

In Sonatype Nexus you can add a proxy repository and optional enter Basic Authentication.

The username and password fields get saved in the server in nexus.xml. 
I had problems to login with a password that had ampersand "&" in it. 
The problem is that Nexus has a bug or missing feature (for me, it is a bug) and it saves it as &. You can verify this by setting the "org.apache.http" logger to trace and then it prints the Base64 each time you try to use the repository. When you decode the Base64 you see how your password was really saved.

I tried to backslash it or use & but Nexus did save them properly as well. Is there a way to enter the spacial characters in Nexus?

I use Nexus 2.11

There was a known bug https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-4877 but they fixed it only for the admin.

Answer (score 1):

It is known to Sonatype.

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-9043

But they won't fix it for Nexus 2.X , just in Nexus 3.X

There is a work around , as mentioned in the post

> As a workaround you can put the plain text password into the nexus.xml while nexus isn't running, and then start the server and save the administration/server configuration. The password will get encrypted.